# C# project: can no longer see design view for existing file

Tags: c#, webforms, design-view

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.7.7 & MS .Net Framework v4.8.09037. I created a web form & properly saw design view & html views. I did a lot of work on it, saved it, & closed the project. When I reopened the project the next day & opened that web form, all other views were gone & all I had was the raw html (i.e. no view options at all). How do I get back to seeing the design view as well as the HTML view like when I 1st created the form? I've poked around in the various menu options but nothing I've tried has fixed the problem. I used VS 2003 for many years but I'm new to VS 2022. Help! I'm assuming it's something obvious that I just haven't found but, as I said, I haven't found anything & I'm thoroughly stuck.

I've checked & tried every menu option that looked even remotely like it might help, but nothing has made any difference or helped. I've also tried Shift-F7 but that did nothing at all.

Comment: Do you have the solution loaded or are you in Folder view in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: I have a solution loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, either you re-installed vs or did somthing HUGE that you not telling us about.

But, there are several things I would check.

First up, did you install the webforms workflows. If they are not installed, then you can't develop or work on a webforms project.

So, make sure under tools->Get Tools and features, you have selected the legacy web form bits and parts. (as noted, this is starnge that the day before this worked - so I can thus only conclude you delete vs, or re-installed - but you leaving out SOME BIG HUGE MASSVIE detail you NOT sharing with us).

Also, is this asp.net web site applicaiton, or a asp.net web site? (this matters huge here).

Assuming you had/have a .sln file (then that is a asp.net website application), then all should work.

Ok, back to installing the workflows,

So, from above, make sure these are installed/selected:

[image]

And if you had reports and/or  are using 4.8, then this:

[image]

Ok, assume a reboot and restart?

Then you want to enable the legacy webforms desinger.

Tools->options->web forms designer.

[image]

And of course you need to close vs for above to take effect.

Comment: I have related everything I did. Leaving something out would be stupid when asking for help (I know some people do it, but I did user support for almost 30 years so I don't). This started happening when I was running VS 17.7.6. I upgraded to 17.7.7 thinking that that might fix the problem but it made no difference.

So far it's just an application intended for a web site but currently just sitting on my PC. I plan on doing as much development this way as possible then move it to a hosted web site somewhere.

The list of what I have installed is too long for a comment here.

Comment: I have the "ASP.NET & Web Development" package/components & am installing the other items on your 1st checklist. I've also updated as per your 2nd checklist. Once this is all done (the extra installs & the reboot) I'll be back with an update.

Comment: Albert D. Kallal:
Updates installed with a reboot & all option changes done. Situation unchanged & problem remains. BTW, I just noticed that this problem is affecting other files in my project/solution (i.e. the std. created-by-default index file).

Comment: If you create a new test project,  say asp.net framework web application,  do those web forms look OK in design mode? In other words does this issue exist with all your webform projects or just the one project? (which thus suggests a damaged project , or that the prg/sln file been messed  with). So does this issue exist with all projects or just one?

Comment: I tried that & it works now! HIP-HIP-HOORAY! The new test project is a ASP.Net Web Application using C#. My problematic project was something different (an "ASP.Net Web Form" I think) & that may have been the source of my problem. THANK YOU TO ALL WHO OFFERED IDEAS, SUGGESTIONS, & RECOMMENDATIONS! If I have further problems, this is  *DEFINITELY* where I'll turn to for help.

Comment: Just keep in mind that MVC projects don't have a desinger. So, only a webforms project, and only .net framework (not .net core) will have the designer. So, there are 2 choices (asp.net web site -- I suggest NOT using this, but it will have webform designers). Then there is a asp.net web forms "application" .net framework (this one I recommend). All other choices will not have the webform designer.